# Unix: fast 'remove directory' for cleaning up daily builds

Tags: build, solaris, aix

Is there a faster way to remove a directory then simply submitting

```
rm -r -f *directory*
```

? I am asking this because our daily cross-platform builds are really huge (e.g. 4GB per build). So the harddisks on some of the machines are frequently running out of space.

This is namely the case for our AIX and Solaris platforms.

Maybe there are 'special' commands for directory remove on these platforms?

PASTE-EDIT (moved my own separate answer into the question):

I am generally wondering why 'rm -r -f' is so slow. Doesn't 'rm' just need to modify the '..' or '.' files to de-allocate filesystem entries.

something like

```
mv *directory* /dev/null
```

would be nice.

Comment: I'm not being specious; buy bigger hard disks.  4GB is not so big in the world of TB storage.

Comment: What filesystem is this?

Comment: I've heard of 'facetious' but 'specious' is a new one on me. +1 :p

Comment: >> GrzegorzOledzki wrote: What filesystem is this?
 
on AIX it is 'jfs'

on the Linux build machine it is 'ext3'

on the Solaris build machine it is ???. I don't know. Have to check tomorrow.

Comment: @Vokuhila-Oliba: This is totally OT, but where does your name come from? I don't get it but think it's hilarious. Being german, I get the first part but not the second?

Comment: @Pekka: VorneKurzHintenLang-OberlippenBart - see www.wikipedia.de ;-)

Comment: It is `mkfs` (it has to be on a separate partition).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For deleting a directory from a filesystem, rm is your fastest option.
On linux, sometimes we do our builds (few GB) in a ramdisk, and it has a really impressive delete speed :) You could also try different filesystems, but on AIX/Solaris you may not have many options...

If your goal is to have the directory $dir empty *now*, you can rename it, and delete it later from a background/cron job:

```
mv "$dir" "$dir.old"
mkdir "$dir"
# later
rm -r -f "$dir.old"
```

Another trick is that you create a seperate filesystem for $dir, and when you want to delete it, you just simply re-create the filesystem. Something like this:

```
# initialization
mkfs.something /dev/device
mount /dev/device "$dir"


# when you want to delete it:
umount "$dir"
# re-init
mkfs.something /dev/device
mount /dev/device "$dir"
```

Comment: "umount 'temp-fs' and re-create" is such a nice idea!

I am accepting this as the best answer!

Comment: this also meshes well with using LVM to allocate a new filesystem from some free space and deallocate it afterwards. or to base your new filesystem on template using LVM's snapshot feature.

Answer (score 20):

I forgot the source of this trick but it works:

```
EMPTYDIR=$(mktemp -d)
rsync -r --delete $EMPTYDIR/ dir_to_be_emptied/
```

Comment: Source (maybe): http://www.quora.com/File-Systems/How-can-someone-rapidly-delete-400-000-files

Comment: I would love to understand *why* the rsync approach is so much faster

Comment: I don't think it is faster, or if it is, it's highly dependent on filesystem and other factors.  I made 1000000 files and used `rm -rf foo/`, took 3 minutes.  Then I tried this, but killed it when it took over twice as long.

Comment: @MarkLopes Try WayBackMachine from archive.org.

Comment: See also here
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37329/efficiently-delete-large-directory-containing-thousands-of-files

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37329/efficiently-delete-large-directory-containing-thousands-of-files

Comment: You can add this link for reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20130929001850/http://linuxnote.net/jianingy/en/linux/a-fast-way-to-remove-huge-number-of-files.html

Comment: @RobLatham, you can refer this to get some numbers on why this works: https://serverfault.com/a/328305/1034612

Answer (score 7):

`rm -r directory` works by recursing depth-first down through *directory*, deleting files, and deleting the directories on the way back up. It has to, since you cannot delete a directory that is not empty.

Long, boring details: Each file system object is represented by an inode in the file system, which has file system-wide, flat array of inodes.[1] If you just deleted *directory* without first deleting its children then the children would remain allocated, but without any pointers to them. (`fsck` checks for that kind of thing when it runs, since it represents file system damage.)

[1] That may not be strictly true for every file system out there, and there may be a file system that works the way you describe. It would possibly require something like a garbage collector. However, all the common ones I know of *act* like fs objects are owned by inodes, and directories are lists of name/inode number pairs.

Comment: +1, this is the explanation I was looking for when I searched and found this question.

Answer (score 6):

On AIX at least, you should be using LVM, the logical volume manager. All our systems bundle all the physical hard drive into a single volume group and then create one big honkin' file system out of that.

That way, you can add physical devices to your machine at will and increase the size of your file system to whatever you need.

One other solution I've seen is to allocate a trash directory on each file system and use a combination of `mv` and a `find` `cron` job to tackle the space problem.

Basically, have a `cron` job that runs every ten minutes and executes:

```
rm -rf /trash/*
rm -rf /filesys1/trash/*
rm -rf /filesys2/trash/*
```

Then, when you want your specific directory on that file system recycled, use something like:

```
mv /filesys1/overnight /filesys1/trash/overnight
```

and, within the next ten minutes your disk space will start being recovered. The `filesys1/overnight` directory will immediately be available for use even before the trashed version has started being deleted.

It's important that the trash directory be on the same filesystem as the directory you want to get rid of, otherwise you have a massive copy/delete operation on your hands rather than a relatively quick move.

Answer (score 3):

If `rm -rf` is slow, perhaps you are using a "sync" option or similar, which is writing to the disk too often.  On Linux ext3 with normal options, `rm -rf` is very quick.

One option for fast removal which would work on Linux and presumably also on various Unixen is to use a loop device, something like:

```
hole temp.img $[5*1024*1024*1024]  # create a 5Gb "hole" file
mkfs.ext3 temp.img
mkdir -p mnt-temp
sudo mount temp.img mnt-temp -o loop
```

The "hole" program is one I wrote myself to create a large empty file using a "hole" rather than allocated blocks on the disk, which is much faster and doesn't use any disk space until you really need it.  http://sam.nipl.net/coding/c-examples/hole.c

I just noticed that GNU coreutils contains a similar program "truncate", so if you have that you can use this to create the image:

```
truncate --size=$[5*1024*1024*1024] temp.img
```

Now you can use the mounted image under mnt-temp for temporary storage, for your build.  When you are done with it, do this to remove it:

```
sudo umount mnt-temp
rm test.img
rmdir mnt-temp
```

I think you will find that removing a single large file is much quicker than removing lots of little files!

If you don't care to compile my "hole.c" program, you can use dd, but this is much slower:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=temp.img bs=1024 count=$[5*1024*1024]  # create a 5Gb allocated file
```

Comment: This sounds like a 'special' solution. But if it works on AIX/solaris I can give it a try. For Linux I do not have this problems since the harddisk is such big that it is not an issue.

Comment: you can also use `dd`'s "seek" command and a count of zero to create files with holes.

Comment: You can do this sort of thing on any OS that has support for loop devices or logical volume management - create a temporary file system in a file or on the LvM, do your work in it, then just delete the whole filesystem (remove the file), which should be almost instantaneous, like deleting a large DVD image or whatever from your disk.  The example commands I gave are for Linux, but the same thing should be possible on any *nix works it's salt, maybe even on 'doze.

Answer (score 2):

I think that actually there is nothing else than "rm -rf" as you quoted to delete your directories.

to avoid doing it manually over and over you can cron daily a script that recursively deletes all the build directories of your build root directory if they're "old enough" with something like :

```
find <buildRootDir>/* -prune -mtime +4 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

(here mtime +4 indicates "any file older than 4 days)

Another way would be to configure your builder (if it allows such things) to crush the previous build with the current one.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into this as well.

I had a dir with 600,000+ files.

rm * would fail, because there are too many entries.

`find . -exec rm {} \;` was nice, and deleting ~750 files every 5 seconds. Was checking the rm rate via another shell.

So, instead I wrote a short script to rm many files at once. Which obtained about ~1000 files every 5 seconds. The idea is to put as many files into 1 rm command as you can to increase the efficiency.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
string="";
count=0;
for i in $(cat filelist);do
    string="$string $i";
    count=$(($count + 1));
  if [[ $count -eq 40 ]];then
    count=1;
    rm $string
    string="";
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris, this is the fastest way I have found.

```
find /dir/to/clean -type f|xargs rm
```

If you have files with odd paths, use

```
find /dir/to/clean -type f|while read line; do echo "$line";done|xargs rm
```

Comment: i agree, just tried the first command with xargs and it is WAY faster than anything else here, in particular when running on slow disks.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
perl -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
Please refer below link:
http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

Needed to delete 700 Gbytes from dozens of directories on AWS EBS 1 TB disk (ext3) before copying remainder to a new 200 Gbyte XFS volume. It was taking hours leaving that volume at 100%wa. Since the disk IO and server time are not free, this took only a fraction of a second per directory.

where /dev/sdb
is an empty volume of any size

directory_to_delete=/ebs/var/tmp/

mount /dev/sdb $directory_to_delete

nohup rsync -avh /ebs/ /ebs2/

Answer (score 1):

I coded a small Java application RdPro (Recursive Directory Purge tool) which is faster than rm. It also can remove target directories user specified under a root.Works for both Linux/Unix and Windows. It has both a command line version and a GUI version.

https://github.com/mhisoft/rdpro

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete more than 3,00,000 files in windows. I had cygwin installed. Luckily i had all the primary directory in a database. Created a for loop and based on line entry and delete using rm -rf

Answer (score 0):

I just use `find ./ -delete` in the folder to empty, and it has deleted 620000 directories (total size) 100GB in arround 10 minutes.

Source : a comment in this site https://www.slashroot.in/comment/1286#comment-1286

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove hundreds of thousands of daily build tiny files ( that will consume your useful memory ) from your Linux server, the below Perl command helped me a lot. This is the most efficient way I know and use. You might try this for your solution.

```
cd /home/admin/tmp or cd yourdirectory    
perl -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

**Note:** Most of the usage is in the **/home/admin/tmp** directory. Also,
I do not recommend using that command in crontab. You can use find instead as it is more customizable and you can check and delete session files older than 30 minutes for example.